# Sphinx documentation in Django

Tags: django, python-sphinx, jinja2

I am currently integrating sphinx generated documentation in my Django app. I want documentation to extend my app templates. The HTML generated by Sphinx should look like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
...
```

My sphinx theme template looks is:

```
{{ '{% extends "base.html" %}' }}
{{ '{% block content %}' }}
...
```

Is there nicer way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with that?  How could it possibly be nicer?

Answer (score 5):

We use the JSONHTMLBuilder:

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinxcontrib.serializinghtml.jsonhtmlbuilder

The contents of the JSON file can be more easily inserted into a page.

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#serialization-builder-details

You read the JSON doc and then render it into your template.

```
def someView( request, topic ):
    # use settings.SOME_DIRECTORY + path info to find the JSON file
    with something as source:
        doc= json.loads( source )
    render_to_response( 'page.template', doc )
```

Something similar to that can work.

Comment: Thanks. Somebody recommended django-sphinxdoc, which I wasn't aware of. It's doing pretty much the same and also adds search to it.